# function not working properly, codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

The function is fetching data from the database, but the issue is, it is not fetching the next row after printing the first row.

Kindly check and tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
Public function Return_Config($P_name, $WW, $KPI) {
    log_message('debug', 'hd');
    log_message('debug', $P_name . ' ' . $WW . ' ' . $KPI);
    $P_name .= '_one_voice_perf_measured';
    $select_query = "SELECT config FROM $P_name WHERE KPI = '$KPI' AND Config = '$WW'";
    //echo $select_query;

    $query = $this->db->query($select_query);
    if ($query->row() > '0') {
        return $query->row()->config;
    } else {
        return 'Not Measured';
    }
}
```

It is going directly to the else part. please help

Answer (score 2):

This is because you are using `->row()` instead use `->result()`, like:

```
Public function Return_Config($P_name, $WW, $KPI)
{
    log_message('debug', 'hd');
    log_message('debug', $P_name . ' ' . $WW . ' ' . $KPI);
    $P_name.= '_one_voice_perf_measured';
    $select_query = "SELECT config FROM $P_name WHERE KPI = '$KPI' AND Config = '$WW'";

    // echo $select_query;

    $query = $this->db->query($select_query);
    if (!empty($query->result()))
    {
        return $query->result();
    }
    else
    {
        return 'Not Measured';
    }
}
```

More details at https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/results.html

Comment: I'm getting this error: A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Array to string conversion

Filename: Performance_Summery_View/PerformanceSummery.php

Line Number: 29

Comment: Which is the line 29?

Comment: the function name itself

Comment: @HardipinderSingh Can you provide the code of how you are calling this method?

Comment: it is showing too long, but to give you a basic idea, I'm directly calling it from the controller and havng it displayed in the form of a table. This function will fetch one row of the database.

Comment: @HardipinderSingh Try using pastebin.com for code. Becuase if you are trying to `echo` its output directly it will cause error.

Comment: so sorry bro, seriously didn't understand you...should I use pastebin instead of echo in code?

Comment: @HardipinderSingh I am unable to see the error. I am sorry. You might consider doing a deeper debugging.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 Public function Return_Config($P_name,$WW,$KPI){
      log_message('debug','hd');
      log_message('debug', $P_name.' '.$WW.' '.$KPI);
            $P_name .= '_one_voice_perf_measured';
        $select_query = "SELECT config FROM $P_name WHERE KPI = '$KPI' AND Config = '$WW'";
        //echo $select_query;

        $query = $this->db->query($select_query)->row_array();
        if (!empty($query)){
          return query['config'];
           } 
      else{
                return 'Not Measured' ;
               }
    }
```